# How to display data that's in an input text type in an asp.net textbox from a java datepicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am using a java datepicker, now when i click on the input control it displays a calendar and when i pick a date it displays it in the input type text control. now i want it to display in a textbox instead(as a side note am thinking of changing the type text to type button)
here is the javascript code

```
    window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
    useMode: 2,
    target: "inputField",
    dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
```

and the controls

```
    <input type="text" size="12" id="inputField" name="inputField" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" name="txtDateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have already tried changing the target to txtDateTime, but it gives an object required error

Comment: What's the rendered ID of `txtDateTime` in the browser? http://forums.asp.net/t/1738476.aspx/1

Comment: @TimSchmelter When i run the page it shows this as my textbox id ctl00_mainContent_txtDateTime ...don't know if that is what you are asking

Comment: @TimSchmelter awesome, i checked the link out and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help, i was thinking something like that but i tried <%=txtDateTime.ClientSideID%> and that didn't work so i thought it can't be that. But again thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're using a MasterPage. Note that server controls' IDs are genereated dynamically from ASP.NET to ensure that they are unique. This is the problem here because javascript searches a control with ID=txtDateTime which it cannot found since it's actual ID is `ctl00_mainContent_txtDateTime`. If this ID is used only once on the page anyway, you can set the TextBox' [ClientIdMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to `Static`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment TimSchmelter made is correct, so what i did was simply change my target value

```
    new JsDatePick({
    useMode: 2,
    target: "ctl00_mainContent_txtDate",
    dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y"
    });
```

to the actual ASP.NET generated ID(check by right clicking on web page and selecting view source). So TimSchmelter thanks for the answer... =)